# Object as a select value in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**JSON Object**

```
export class Car {
  ID: String;
  dors: [{
    number: Number,
    postion: {
        x: String,
        y: String,
        z: String,
    }
  }]

}
```

How do I set `position` as the value of a `Select`? I have tried `value={{}}` but it can only be used for a string. I have tried `ngValue` but it seems not to change the behavior. It keeps bringing just the `string` that I show in the `select` so I got not the correct way to do it. Is it possible?

I want to set `car.dors.position` as a `value`.

What I need to do is something like this:

[image: Image of code]

I get all the information of the object, but I want to get `car.doors[i]` as a value.

Comment: ` I have tried several ways to do` , please explain what you have tried?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what didn't work? It might help us understand what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Done it. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Car {
  ID: String;
  dors:Array<any>= [{
    number: Number,
    postion: {
        x: String,
        y: String,
        z: String,
    }
  }]

}
```

read more about class definitions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: The object is already an array, that s why I have []. That s not what I am asking

Comment: sorry but you have class error definition, about value in option try 
[value]="your object"
but i`m not sure, i think in option tag you should operate only with simple object types